# Using Microsoft.IdentityModel in an SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to use the `Microsoft.IdentityModel` dll in an SSIS package.

In a regular C# application, I would add the assemblies to the app.config file as show in this website [adding Microsoft.IdentityModel](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2013/08/the-configuration-section-cannot-be.html)

But I can't use this in SSIS because their is no app.config in a script component.

I've tried adding an app.config and adding the sections to the app.config but that does not work.

I have also tried importing an .xml file for the package configuration.

Also the exact error I get when I debug my script is:

```
"ID7027: Could not load the identity configuration 
 because no <system.identityModel> configuration section was found."
```

Answer (score 1):

We were using `SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;`  to get the handlers.

We changed it to use

```
                    SecurityTokenHandlerCollection collection = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();

                token = collection.ReadToken(xmlReader.ReadSubtree());
```

Here is how the code is used

```
        private static SecurityToken ConvertBearerTokenTextToSecurityToken(string tokenText)
    {
        SecurityToken token = null;

        // ConfigSections must be added to App.Config in order for this line to work - this section must be right after the <configuration> node

        //<configSections>
        //  <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
        //  <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        //  <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        //</configSections>

        //SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(tokenText))
        {
            using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                if (!xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Assertion"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Assertion not found!");
                }

                SecurityTokenHandlerCollection collection = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();

                token = collection.ReadToken(xmlReader.ReadSubtree()); 
            }
        }

        return token;
    }
```